# Passing values between forms with npyscreen

Tags: python-curses

I am trying to create a simple `npyscreen` curses application in python that requests user input on one screen, and then verifies it for the user on another screen.

Mostly, this is an effort to understand how values are stored and retrieved from within `npyscreen`.  I am sure I am missing something simple, but I have been unable to find (or understand?) the answer within the documentation.

Sample code below which will not pass the value properly:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import npyscreen as np

class EmployeeForm(np.Form):
    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.switchForm('CONFIRMFM')

    def create(self):
        self.myName = self.add(np.TitleText, name='Name')
        self.myDepartment = self.add(np.TitleSelectOne, scroll_exit=True, max_height=3, name='Department', values = ['Department 1', 'Department 2', 'Department 3'])
        self.myDate = self.add(np.TitleDateCombo, name='Date Employed')

class EmployeeConfirmForm(np.Form):
    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def create(self):
        self.value = None
        self.wgName   = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Name:",)
        self.wgDept = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Dept:")
        self.wgEmp      = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Employed:")

    def beforeEditing(self):
        if self.value:
            self.name = "Is this correct?"
            self.wgName.value   = self.myName.value
            self.wgDept.value = self.myDepartment.value
            self.wgEmp.value      = self.myDate.value

    def on_cancel(self):
        self.parentApp.switchFormPrevious()


class myApp(np.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm('MAIN', EmployeeForm, name='Employee Entry')
        self.addForm('CONFIRMFM', EmployeeConfirmForm, name='Employee Confirmation')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp = myApp().run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found a straightforward way to directly pass variables between forms. However, you can work around this by using variables that have a global scope among forms.

The `NPSAppManaged` app class runs completely encapsulated, so if you try to declare global variables at the top of the Python file, the forms within will not have access to them. Instead, declare the variables inside the `NPSAppManaged` app class before the `onStart` method as shown below.

```py
class myApp(np.NPSAppManaged):

    # declare variables here that have global scope to all your forms
    myName, myDepartment, myDate = None, None, None

    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm('MAIN', EmployeeForm, name='Employee Entry')
        self.addForm('CONFIRMFM', EmployeeConfirmForm, name='Employee Confirmation')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp = myApp().run()
```

You can then access these variables using `self.parentApp.[variable name]` as follows:

```py
class EmployeeConfirmForm(np.Form):
    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def create(self):
        self.add(np.FixedText, value = "Is this correct?")
        self.wgName = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Name:", value = self.parentApp.myName)
        self.wgDept = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Dept:", value = self.parentApp.myDepartment)
        self.wgEmp = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Employed:", value = self.parentApp.myDate)

    def on_cancel(self):
        self.parentApp.switchFormPrevious()
```

*Note*: you don't need to have a separate `beforeEditing` method since the values will be loaded directly into `EmployeeConfirmForm` during the `create` method from the app class global variables.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use getForm before switchForm to pass the values. The following works for me using python2 to pass the name. Passing other values should be similar. I'm very much learning this myself but please comment if you have further questions.

```
import npyscreen as np

class EmployeeForm(np.ActionForm):
    def create(self):
        self.myName = self.add(np.TitleText, name='Name')
        self.myDepartment = self.add(np.TitleSelectOne, scroll_exit=True, max_height=3, name='Department', values = ['Department 1', 'Department 2', 'Department 3'])
        self.myDate = self.add(np.TitleDateCombo, name='Date Employed')

    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.getForm('CONFIRMFM').wgName.value = self.myName.value
        self.parentApp.switchForm('CONFIRMFM')

class EmployeeConfirmForm(np.Form):
    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def create(self):
        self.value = None
        self.wgName  = self.add(np.TitleFixedText, name = "Name:",)
        self.wgDept = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Dept:")
        self.wgEmp      = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Employed:")

    def on_cancel(self):
        self.parentApp.switchFormPrevious()

class myApp(np.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm('MAIN', EmployeeForm, name='Employee Entry')
        self.addForm('CONFIRMFM', EmployeeConfirmForm, name='Employee Confirmation')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp = myApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign values (including the value returned by addForm) to self.whatever.
So if you do

```
self.myAppValue = 2
self.mainForm = self.addForm('MAIN', MainForm, ...)
self.form2 = self.addForm('FORM2', Form2, ...)
```

you can use these in any form

```
self.parentApp.myAppValue
self.parentApp.mainForm.main_form_widget.main_form_value
```

And in myApp() you can do

```
self.mainForm.main_form_widget.main_form_value
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems during development as the documentation is not very detailed about passing values between forms.

I have added a few modification, the first one was changing `Form` to `ActionForm` in the confirmation form to have access to *ok* and *cancel* buttons. Secondly, the values on the confirmation form should not be editable as this is a confirmation. You can press cancel to edit on the previous form. The last one was passing the first element of the department list rather than the value - it would be just a list index. I hope it helps a little.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import npyscreen as np


class EmployeeForm(np.Form):

    def create(self):
        self.myName = self.add(np.TitleText, name='Name')
        self.myDepartment = self.add(np.TitleSelectOne, scroll_exit=True, max_height=3, name='Department', values = ['Department 1', 'Department 2', 'Department 3'])
        self.myDate = self.add(np.TitleDateCombo, name='Date Employed')

    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.switchForm('CONFIRMFM')
        self.parentApp.getForm('CONFIRMFM').wgName.value = self.myName.value
        self.parentApp.getForm('CONFIRMFM').wgDept.value = self.myDepartment.values[0]
        self.parentApp.getForm('CONFIRMFM').wgEmp.value = self.myDate.value


class EmployeeConfirmForm(np.ActionForm):

    def create(self):
        self.add(np.FixedText, value="Is this correct?", editable=False)
        self.wgName = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Name:", editable=False)
        self.wgDept = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Dept:", editable=False)
        self.wgEmp = self.add(np.TitleText, name = "Employed:", editable=False)

    def on_ok(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def on_cancel(self):
        self.parentApp.switchFormPrevious()


class myApp(np.NPSAppManaged):

    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm('MAIN', EmployeeForm, name='Employee Entry')
        self.addForm('CONFIRMFM', EmployeeConfirmForm, name='Employee Confirmation')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp = myApp().run()
```